# On an exercise from Weibel's book on homological algebra

Tags: ct.category-theory, homological-algebra, abelian-categories

I was revising some old postgraduate notes of mine in homological algebra (written during a postgrad course on the topic, I had taken more than ten ;) years ago) and I came accross the following problem: Weibel's book "*An introduction to homological algebra*" (which had been among my textbooks by that time), states the following exercise: ([ex. $1.4.4$](http://assets.cambridge.org/97805214/35000/sample/9780521435000ws.pdf)):

> Consider the homology $H_*(C)$ of $C$ as a chain complex with zero differentials. Show that if the complex $C$ is split, then there is a chain homotopy equivalence between $C$ and $H_*(C)$. Give an example in which the converse fails.

I've solved the exercise but i've failed to find a counterexample for the converse. In fact, I think the converse also holds, but I haven't yet found the time to clear it up. Can somebody help ?

Comment: Consider any short exact sequence as a complex $C$ concentrated in three consecutive degrees.  If this complex is null homotopic, the same is true after applying any additive functor $F$.  Yet typically the homology of $F(C)$ is nonzero (and this is the main motivation behind the development of homological algebra).

Comment: @JasonStarr how does this address the question?

Comment: @GabrielC.Drummond-Cole.  I misread the OP's question.  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are correct, the converse also holds. This is a mistake in Weibel, see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1405990/99887).

Comment: aahh... ok, i also saw the link to the corrections to the book. Thank you!